# How to ReRun a Function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I make this function recallable? Right now, it only reruns after the page is reloaded. I want it to work all the time. Apparently, I am not using `unbind` right.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.viewAll').bind("click.myEvent", function(){
                $('.mobileNavBtn, #shopNavTabBtn, #sec0').click();
                $(this).unbind("click.myEvent");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#sec0").offset().top
                }, 2000);
                return false;
            });
        })
    </script>
```

This is my original function:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.viewAll').on('click', function(){
                $('.mobileNavBtn, #shopNavTabBtn, #sec0').click();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#sec0").offset().top
                }, 2000);
                return false;
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: firstly, instead of `bind` use `.on()`. Secondly, why don't you remove the `unbind`. That should make it callable.

Comment: My original function does have .on( ). My function is callable, but I need it to be repeatable. {when someone clicks a second time, i'd like the function to rerun}

Comment: You are binding a specific functionality on a click event. It will execute only when that click happens. Having said this, you want execute this on page load AND on the click event?

Comment: I'm a little confused, as it seems your original function does allow the user to click the .viewAll element to scroll to the #sec0 element as many times as they want (btw you only need $('body') it seems, instead of $('html, body'))... but it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/s7f87a2n/

Comment: @mark.hch Thanks for the input. Will try the corrections. When I try rerunning the function by click, the animation starts to work then reloads the page instead.

Comment: Is the button inside a form? If so, it's default action will submit the form. If this is the case, add the event parameter to the click function, and call event.preventDefault();

Comment: I have actually tried that, and it doesn't seem to work. I think it is something in the CMS and their way of handling their mobile slide out menu.  Any other tips on overriding?  Thanks for your input, btw!

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).unbind("click.myEvent");` here you are unbinding the event listener.  The result of this is your event only firing once (as it will stop listening after the first time it is triggered.)

A nicer cleaner way of achieving that functionality in jQuery is to attach the event handler using the [jQuery one method](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

On the other hand, if you are trying to only listen to the element while the animation is not running, you could attach the event listener, and remove it when the animation begins.  Reattach the event after the animation.  The example you provided would look like this:

```
$('.viewAll').on('click', viewAllClick);
function viewAllClick(evt) {
    $('.mobileNavBtn, #shopNavTabBtn, #sec0').click();
    //detach this event
    $('.viewAll').off('click', viewAllClick);

    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#sec0").offset().top,
    }, {
        done: function () {
            //reattach the event
            $('.viewAll').on('click', viewAllClick);
        },
        duration: 2000
    });
}
```

I would double check your animate call to ensure it is doing what you actually intend.

See this [plunker for a similar example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHbZUsI3OrIHbLF378or?p=preview).  Click on the text and observed that animate is only logged after the animation the event is reattached, while clicked will fire every time you click the text.